# display comment and replies?

Tags: php, mysql, yii2

I am trying to display comment and replies but I don't really know how to do it. This is my table.

```
comment_id | byy  | user_comment   | topic_id    | parent_id | 
   1       |obi   |comment 1       |    1        |    0      |
   2       |chima |comment 2       |    1        |    0      |
   3       |eze   |comment 1 reply |    1        |    1      |
   4       |david |comment 2 reply |    1        |    2      |
```

This code I wrote is just to display only the comment but I want the comment to show the replies of the comment if there any. Before it displays the next comment

```
<?php
  $querycomment = comment::find()->where(['topic_id'=> Yii::$app->getRequest()->getQueryParam('id')])->all();

  foreach ($querycomment as $detail) {
    if($detail['parent_id']==0) {
      echo 'Country Name: '.$detail['user_comment'].'</br>';
      echo 'State Name: '.$detail['byy'].'</br>';
      echo 'City Name: '.$detail['name'].'</br>';
      echo '</br>';
    }
  }
?>
```

Comment: For comments reply, is there any max depth level is there or it will be infinitive?

Comment: it should be expandable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the actual code of the following `pseudocode`:

```
<?php 
// print comments and/or replies body
function print_comments( $topic_id, $parent_id ) {
   $all_comments = Comment::find()
               ->where(
                   'topic_id' => $topic_id,
                   'parent_id' => $parent_id
               )->all();

    if( empty($all_comment) ) {
      return "";
    }

    $comments = '<ul>';
    foreach( $all_comments as $comment ) {
        $comments .= '<li>
            <p> '.$comment->user_comment.' </p>
            <p> by: '.$comment->byy.' </p>';

            // print replies
            $comments .= print_comments( $topic_id, $comment->comment_id ); // recursive

        $comments .= '</li>';
    }
    $comments .= '</ul>';

    return $comments;
}
?>
```

Put the above code on the top of your view file. Now use tho following line where you want to show/echo your comments and replies.

```
<?php echo print_comments( Yii::$app->getRequest()->getQueryParam('id'), 0); ?>
```

---

*(previous answer)*

You can try to follow this `pseudocode`:

```
print_comments( queryParam(id),  0); // parent_id = 0

// print comments and/or replies body
print_comments ( $topic_id, $parent_id ) {
   $all_comments = Comment::find()
               ->where(
                   topic_id => $topic_id,
                   parent_id => $parent_id
               )->all();

    if( $all_comment count = zero )
      return

    <ul>
    foreach( $all_comments as $comment ) {
        <li>
            <p> $comment->user_comment </p>
            <p> by: $comment->byy </p>

            // print replies
            print_comments( $topic_id, $comment->comment_id ); // recursive

        </li>
    }
    </ul>
}
```

**Pros:** Easier to understand and implement.
**Cons:** Uses a lot of query.

Any other way to overcome cons??
*Just keep in mind that when used with pagination this method of doing is trickier to implement.*

1. Use single query to get all comments and replies
2. format all of them to comment => replies relation
3. loop through the relation and show it

Comment: you dont understand my question

Comment: i have added the actual code for the previous pseudocode. the answer i was trying to give you and the answer @user3360140 is giving you are same btw.

Comment: i feel so stupid. your answer is right. how can i make the replies shift a little to the right

Comment: use css. for example all `ul li` are first level comment, `ul li li` are replies to first level comment, `ul li li li` are replies to reply and so on.

Answer (score 3):

Im not familiar with Yii. But you can achieve this using recursion. Try to implement sometihng similar to the below:

```
function show_replies($parent_id = 0, $level = 0) {
    $query = "select * from comments where parent_id = $parent_id";
    $result = mysql_query($query);
    if (!$result || !mysql_num_rows($result)) {
        return;
    }

    while($detail = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
        $space ='';
        for ($i = 0; $i < $level; $i++) {
            $space .= "--";
        }

        echo $space.'Country Name: '.$detail['user_comment'].'</br>';
        echo $space.'State Name: '.$detail['byy'].'</br>';
        echo $space.'City Name: '.$detail['name'].'</br>';
        show_replies($detail['comment_id'], $level + 1);
    }
}

show_replies();
```

Comment: mysql_query has been deprecated so i used mysqli . and it sqay what is data

Comment: sorry about the type. fixed it

Comment: new "error Trying to get property of non-object" . it directs me to $detail->id line

Comment: I initially used `mysql_fetch_object` in the sample code. Forgot to change that line. Just fixed it. Please check.

Comment: I tested the code in my computer with some sample data and it seems to work fine. `mysqli_connect(): (08004/1040): Too many connections` shows up when you open up more than one connection per script. Are you opening multiple mysql connections from your script ?